# How to get member count at on_member_join event in discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I am trying to get membercount at `on_member_join` event in discord.py

My code -

```py
@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
  await bot.get_channel(channel_id1).send(f"Welcome Message")
  memberCount = 0
  for member in member.guild.members:
    if member.bot == False:
      memberCount = memberCount + 1
  await bot.get_channel(channel_id2).edit(name=f"Members: {memberCount}")
```

but the channel with `channel_id2` is not updating and it becomes

```
Member: 0
```

Comment: is the channel_id 1 & 2 are integers? do they exist?

Comment: yes, channel_id 1 and 2 are integers

Comment: Have you enabled Members Intent?

Comment: the channels exists

Comment: yes, i enabled member intents @Ratery

Comment: i Got that, i can make a new function ...

code - 

async def channel_update(guild):
  count = 0
  for member in guild.members:
    if member.bot == False:
      count = count + 1
  await bot.get_channel(channel_id).edit(name=f"Members: {count}")

@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
  await bot.get_channel(channel_id_X).send(f"Welcome Message")
  await channel_update(member.guild)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually i got something, but not sure about it.
can i create a new function to do that -

```py
async def MemberCount(guild):
  mc = 0
  for member in guild:
    if member.bot == False:
      mc = mc + 1
  return mc

@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
  await bot.get_channel(channel_id1).send(f"Welcome Message")
  memberCount = await MemberCount(message.guild)
  await bot.get_channel(channel_id2).edit(name=f"Members: {memberCount}")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
bot = commands.Bot(intents=intents)



@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    guild = bot.get_guild(guild_id)
    channel = bot.get_channel(channel_id)
    mc = guild.member_count
    await channel.send(f"{mc} members")
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This gives total member count (including bots), but i want to get only Human count .....